# Auto word wrapping in a node in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using `TikZ` to make a flow chart demonstrating my scheme step by step. I notice that the word wrapping is not automatic in a node. That is, the line can be extremely long across the whole page.

The MWE is as follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Your Paper}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum width=0.95*\columnwidth, anchor=west}, font=\small]
    \node[block, minimum width=0.95\columnwidth, minimum height=1cm, fill=white, opacity=1, text opacity=1, rounded corners, thick](step1) at (0,0){};
    \node[below=0cm of step1.north, align=left]{\textbf{Step 1}: This is Step one, which is a very very very long sentence. I really hate it when it does not automatically do the wrapping.};
    \node[block, minimum width=0.95\columnwidth, minimum height=1cm, below right=0.9cm and 0cm of step1.south, fill=white, opacity=1, text opacity=1, rounded corners, thick](step2) at (0,0){};
    \node[below=0cm of step2.north, align=left]{\textbf{Step 2}: Step 2 is cute and short.};
    \draw[-stealth](step1.south)--(step2.north)node[pos=0.5, above=0cm]{};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

which renders as
[image]

My current workaround is to manually insert new line, which is very troublesome.

I, therefore, wish to find **an elegant way to achieve the automatic word wrapping in a node of `TikZ`**.

Comment: `align=left` to the node options and set a `text width`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were not getting the expected automatic text wrapping that one would expect using `align=<option>`, because you were setting the `minimum width` key. Provide an appropriate value for `text width` (not for `minimum width`); then `align=<option>` will provide the desired alignment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Your Paper}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{tikzpicture}[
block/.style={
  draw, 
  fill=white, 
  text width=0.95*\columnwidth, 
  anchor=west,
  minimum height=1cm,
  rounded corners 
  }, 
font=\small
]
\node[block,align=left]
  (step1)
  {\textbf{Step 1}: This is Step one, which is a very very very long sentence. I really hate it when it does not automatically do the wrapping.};
\node[block,below=2cm of step1.north,align=center]
  (step2)
  {\textbf{Step 2}: Step 2 is cute and short.};
\draw[-stealth]
  (step1.south)--(step2.north)node[pos=0.5, above=0cm]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also made some simplifications to the original code, suppressing some (apparently unnecessary) nodes.

Comment: This is so awesome, sir. Exactly what I want. Thank you so much!

Comment: @FarticlePilter You're welcome! I updated my answer introducing some simplifications that might be of interest for you. Of course, some of the changes I made were just based on the example posted; you can decide if my changes are what you really need :)

Comment: I cannot thank you more, sir. It goes far beyond an answer. Thanks!! I should acknowledge you in my paper! LOL