# Text Wrapping in tikz node doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like have a few fixed nodes of size 1cm x 1cm.
However, the text inside these nodes should wrap around.

I used the following [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167944/auto-word-wrapping-in-a-node-in-tikz) help to figure out about wrapping text.
However it doesn't seem to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.75cm,auto   , font=\small]

\tikzstyle{block}=[draw, fill=white, text width=1cm, anchor=west,  minimum height=1cm]

 \node [block] [minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1.5cm,align=center] (mb0) {MB};
 \node [block] [right of=mb0] (dmem0) {dmem};
 \node [block] [left of=mb0] (imem0) {imem};
 \node [block] [below of=mb0,align=left] (cmemin0) {cmem\_in};
 \node [block] [right of=cmemin0] (dma0) {DMA};
 \node [block] [right of=dma0] (cmemout0) {cmem\_out};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However you can see in the picture that the text flows outside the box
instead of wrapping around.
[image]

How do I resolve this situation?

Thanks !

Comment: You need some hyphenation points in your text.  It doesn't know where to break.  For example, if I add the text `{sectar-ion}` in one of your nodes, it wraps at the hyphen.

Comment: @T.Verron you will see that I have added this option in `cmemin0` node, but still the text flows out.

Comment: Oh, right, I was only seeing it in "MB". Sorry, deleting my comment.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It works, but what if I don't want hyphen in the text of my node?

Comment: You also need to fix a `text width` to allow hyphenation.

Comment: @Ignasi I mentioned `text width=1cm` in the block style.

Comment: Well a blank space at the desired place (e.g., `cmem _out`) will allow a line break, but that, of course, is not automatic hyphenation.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yes it works. thanks ! its a hack which I didn't know before.

Comment: @Raj: Ups! you're right I haven't seen it. In any case where could be `cmem_in` hyphenated? TeX only know how to break know words, but not estrange ones even more if it contains - or _

Comment: @Ignasi you are right that it doesn't know about the strange words. but just replace the `cmem_in` by `averylonglongstring`. I see that the text still overflows. So probably `-` or space is a must for breaking text.

Comment: You can add hyphenation points with `\-`. It will break the text at that point if need be, otherwise it will be invisible. Still not 100% automatic of course.

Comment: You could add \hspace{0pt} at the points in the words where you want to allow a line break.

Comment: @T.Verron  Thanks.  I couldn't remember the shorthand for `\allowbreak`.  You should offer that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, several problems are stacking in your case.

First, the hyphenation engine cannot guess what is a correct hyphenation for a word like `cmem_in`. I am not even sure there is such a correct hyphenation.

In this case, you need to marks the points where the break is allowed with `\-`.

Second, even for "not so strange" words, like "averylonglongstring", the hyphenation does not happen. The reason is given in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45517/why-does-babel-not-work-in-tikz): the first word of a paragraph is not hyphenated by design.

A suggested workaround is to use `\hspace{0pt}` before such words. Note that in the MWE, `longstring` still flows out of the box, that's because it is a "strange word" again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.75cm,auto   , font=\small]

  \tikzstyle{block}=[draw, fill=white, text width=1cm, anchor=west,  minimum height=1cm]

  \node [block] [minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1.5cm,align=center] (mb0) {MB};
  \node [block] [right of=mb0] (dmem0) {dmem};
  \node [block] [left of=mb0,align=left] (imem0) {averylonglongstring};
  \node [block] [below of=mb0,align=left] (cmemin0) {cmem\-\_in};
  \node [block] [right of=cmemin0,align=left] (dma0) {\hspace{0pt}averylonglongstring};
  \node [block] [right of=dma0,align=left,text width=1.5cm] (cmemout0) {cmem\-\_out};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The correct code that I finally use would be -

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.85cm,auto, font=\small]

\tikzstyle{block}=[draw, fill=white, text width=1cm, anchor=west, align=center, minimum height=1cm]

 \node [block] [minimum width=1.75cm, minimum height=1.75cm] (mb0) {MB};
 \node [block] [right of=mb0,align=center] (dmem0) {dme m};
 \node [block] [left of=mb0] (imem0) {imem};
 \node [block] [below of=mb0,align=center] (cmemin0) {cme m\_in};
 \node [block] [right of=cmemin0,align=center] (dma0) {DMA};
 \node [block] [right of=dma0,align=center] (cmemout0) {cme m\_out};
\end{tikzpicture}
```